# Maven Surefire plugin: what is meaning of filesystem in runOrder?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I wanted to know if my integration tests will run in specific order and looked at the `maven-failsafe-plugin` [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#runOrder), which is

> `runOrder`:
>
> Defines the order the tests will be run in. Supported values are
>   "alphabetical", "reversealphabetical", "random", "hourly"
>   (alphabetical on even hours, reverse alphabetical on odd hours),
>   "failedfirst", "balanced" and "filesystem". Odd/Even for hourly is
>   determined at the time the of scanning the classpath, meaning it could
>   change during a multi-module build. Failed first will run tests that
>   failed on previous run first, as well as new tests for this run.
>   Balanced is only relevant with parallel=classes, and will try to
>   optimize the run-order of the tests to make all tests complete at the
>   same time, reducing the overall execution time. Note that the
>   statistics are stored in a file named .surefire-XXXXXXXXX beside
>   pom.xml, and should not be checked into version control. The "XXXXX"
>   is the SHA1 checksum of the entire surefire configuration, so
>   different configurations will have different statistics files, meaning
>   if you change any config settings you will re-run once before new
>   statistics data can be established.
>
> - Type: `java.lang.String`
> - Since: `2.7`
> - Required: `No`
> - Default: `filesystem`

What is meaning of filesystem order? the order in which files are created?

Answer (score 6):

When you list files in a directory most tools show them in alphabetical order, but their real "default" order is implementation specific.

You can use ls -U to show that order on linux.

from a ls manpage:

```
-U     do not sort; list entries in directory order
```